# Network unclaimed Wifi not available in new installed laptop rtl8821ce

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, networkmanager, realtek

I installed new os debian bullseye in laptop. I cant find wifi option in network manager.

`sudo lshw -C network` gives,

```
...
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0600000-c060ffff
...
```

`lspci` gives output like

```
...
Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
...
```

`lsmod` gives

```
...
rtw88_8821ce           16384  0
rtw88_8821c            77824  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_pci              28672  1 rtw88_8821ce
...
```

After adding backports to the source list, I run

`sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports firmware-realtek`, then is shows `firmware-realtek is already the newest version (20210315-3)`.

I can see that `RTL8821C` is available without backports [here](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-realtek).

output of `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` is `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.0-9-amd64`

Output of `ifconfig`

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16449  bytes 16751257 (15.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13241  bytes 1848301 (1.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 129  bytes 11324 (11.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 129  bytes 11324 (11.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When reinstalling firmware I get below warnings,

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_dmcub.bin for module amdgpu
```

Also `sudo journalctl | grep rtw` returns

```
Nov 18 15:27:26 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtw88/rtw8821c_fw.bin (-2)
Nov 18 15:27:26 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw88/rtw8821c_fw.bin failed with error -2
Nov 18 15:27:26 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to request firmware
Nov 18 15:27:26 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to load firmware
Nov 18 15:27:26 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
Nov 18 15:27:26 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information
Nov 18 15:27:26 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -22
Nov 24 21:38:57 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtw88/rtw8821c_fw.bin
Nov 24 21:38:57 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 24.8.0, H2C version 12
Nov 24 21:38:57 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: rfe 2 isn't supported
Nov 24 21:38:57 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
Nov 24 21:38:57 debian kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information
Nov 30 11:16:48 debian sudo[2358]: username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/modprobe rtw88_8821ce
Nov 30 11:23:31 debian sudo[2561]: username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/modprobe rtw88_8821ce
```

and `sudo dkms status` returns nothing.

I disabled secure boot and reinstalled driver. But not worked.

Comment: please can you add `journalctl | grep rtw` also `dkms status` and if it is uefi install try to disable secureboot in uefi.

Comment: @nobody I updated questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the driver from [this git repository](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce). As said tomaspinho:

> Wi-Fi not working for kernel >= 5.9

> The Linux Kernel 5.9 version comes with a broken rtw88 module developed by Realtek that has poor compatibility with most revision of the 8821ce chip.

```
sudo apt install git bc module-assistant build-essential dkms
sudo m-a prepare
echo "blacklist rtw88_8821ce" |sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Comment: Worked, please change `cd rtl8821cd` to `cd rtl8821ce`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are tearing your hair out over this, and it is an option, the latest Ubuntu 22.04.1 works out of the box with RTL8821CE. Did not even need to click the 'enable proprietary' box. It worked after booting from the USB even before the install.

I would have preferred Debian, have that on my main machine as it is more strictly FOSS than Ubuntu. In this case though it was not critical, and I spent hours trying solutions from Debian non-free, from https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce and from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 and in all cases on Debian 11 Bullseye it did not acknowledge the existence of this RTL8821CE in the slightest.

The accepted solution probably works, but there is likely some subtlety to it that I missed. The search results reveal a lot of misery with that WiFi card on Debian. I will think twice about getting Realtek or a HP PC next time I want to put Linux on it, but hopefully in time Debian will support it without so much drama.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo "options 8821ce wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8821ce.conf
```

and reboot